Name that logic gate!
Given the truth table of a non-trivial symmetric 2-input logic gate, output its name.  The 6 possible input/output pairs are:
0001 -> AND
1110 -> NAND
0111 -> OR
1000 -> NOR
0110 -> XOR
1001 -> XNOR

(where the 4 symbols represent the outputs of the gate for inputs 00,01,10,11 respectively).
Input
You can take the input format to be a single sequence "0001" or [0,0,0,1], or a 2-dimensional array [[0,0],[0,1]] or a function g with g(0,1)=0 etc.  You do not need to handle input other than the 6 cases above.  You can accept False/True (or their equivalent in your language) instead of 0/1 respectively, as long as it is done consistently.  But reversing the values or requiring arbitrary values is not allowed.
Output
The exact string "AND", etc.  You can alternatively use all lower case but it must be done consistently.  If printing, trailing whitespace is allowed.
And no, you can't use NXOR!
This is code-golf, so shortest solution in each language wins.

May the input be the integer corresponding to the binary sequence? (e.g. "1110" -> 14)

@Arnauld I'm going to say no to that. Input should be immediately recognisable as the truth table.

"Input should be immediately recognisable as the truth table." It is if your language understands binary integer literals as many do. Not that the sample of languages I know is very large ...

Python, 46 44 bytes
lambda a,b,_,d:'XN'[a^d:-~a]+'AONRD'[a^b::2]

Attempt This Online!
-2 thanks to dingledooper
Anonymous function taking each truth value as a separate argument. Returns the concatenation of:
'XN'[a^d: ... ]

X, if the output for 11 is 0 (flipped if the output for 00 is 1);
'XN'[ ... :-~a]

N, if the output for 00 is 1;
'AONRD'[a^b::2]

and either AND or OR, depending on the output for 01 (flipped if the output for 00 is 1), by choosing either the even- or odd-indexed elements of AONRD.

-2 bytes: 'XN'[a^d:1+a]

brainfuck, 132 bytes
-[--->+<]>[>,]<<<<[->->->-<<<]>>>[>]<<<<[+++.--->]<------->>>>[>]<-[<<<[>]<.>>[>]]<[[<]<+.+++.<]<[>>]<<[>>----[----<+>]<++.<.>+++.>]

Try it online!
Expects input as a string of 4 ascii digits (terminated with zero byte.) The code starts by generating 255/3=85 (ASCII U), then takes the four inputs, and subtracts the first from the rest. This gives the following memory status. It prints an X if the last cell is zero, an N if the last nonzero is negative, followed by OR if the cell next to it is nonzero (or AND if it is zero.)
0001 -> AND       0  85  0  0  0  1
1110 -> NAND      0  85  0  0  0 -1  
0111 -> OR        0  85  0  1  1  1
1000 -> NOR       0  85  0 -1 -1 -1
0110 -> XOR       0  85  0  1  1  0
1001 -> XNOR      0  85  0 -1 -1  0     

Developed at https://minond.xyz/brainfuck/ . Brief comments below will be improved later.
-[--->+<]         Countdown cell 0 to setup 255/3=85 in cell 1
>[>,]<<<<         Take input in cells 2~5 & move to cell 2 
[->->->-<<<]>>>   Decrement all inputs until cell 2 = 0
[>]<<<<[+++.--->] If cell 5 = 0 print X and end in cell 2
<------->>>>[>]<  Prepare cell 1 to print N and move to last nonzero cell
-[<<<[>]<.>>[>]]  Decrement last nonzero cell and If still nonzero it must be negative so print N  
<[[<]<+.+++.<]    If cell to the left is nonzero print OR and leave pointer to left of all data
<[>>]<<           Search to the left of the current cell for the cell containing N
[>>               If found generate the ASCII for A 
 ----[----<+>]<++.(256-4)/4+2=65 and print it 
<.>+++.>]         Followed by ND


C, 48 45 bytes
char*f(x){return"XOR\0NAND\0XNOR"+(18-x)%12;}

Try it online!
Takes an integer.
Makes use of the properties of C's null-terminated strings: they can overlap if one is a suffix of another, and because they are represented by pointers, adding to the pointer shifts the starting point.

You may save some bytes by printing to stdout using puts instead of returning as a string: f(x){puts("XOR\0NAND\0XNOR"+(18-x)%12);} (40 bytes); Or using -D compiler flag to define f as a macro -Df(x)=("XOR\0NAND\0XNOR"+(18-(x))%12) (37 bytes)

Seems like this input format is unfortunately not allowed :-(

36 bytes

JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes
A solution without a lookup table.
Expects a 4-character binary string.
x=>"XN".slice(x%9%2,1-x&9)+(x%6<2?"AND":"OR")

Try it online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 43 bytes
x=>'NAND1AND1XOR1OR1NOR1XNOR'.split(1)[x%6]

Try it online!
-3 bytes tsh
Trivial. (if) Porting Unrelated String would make it longer

x=>'NAND;AND;XOR;OR;NOR;XNOR'.split\;`[x%6]`

Retina 0.8.2, 41 39 bytes
(.)..\1
X$&
1...
N$&
(.)\1..
AND
\d+
OR

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
(.)..\1
X$&

Prefix X if the first and last digits are the same.
1...
N$&

Prefix N to the first digit if it is a 1.
(.)\1..
AND

Replace the digits with AND if the first and second are the same.
\d+
OR

Otherwise replace the digits with OR.

Google Sheets, 50 48 bytes
=if(A1=D1,"X",)&if(A1,"N",)&if(A1=B1,"AND","OR")

Same score as doubleunary's lookup table. Thanks to doubleunary for a suggestion saving 2 bytes. This is my first time trying to code golf in google sheets, so I may have missed something else.
The 4 inputs should be in A1, B1, C1, D1, formula in E1.


Use three if()s for 48 bytes: =if(A1=D1,"X",)&if(A1,"N",)&if(A1=B1,"AND","OR")

Uiua, 25 bytes
⊂⊙⨬"OR""AND"▽⊓⊟"XN"⊃⤚==

Try it: Uiua pad. This is inspired by Neil's solution in Charcoal.
Uiua, 31 bytes
⊡◿6⋕⊙{⟜↘₁"NAND"⊂@X.⍥₂⊸↘₁"XNOR"}

Try it: Uiua pad. This is a port of l4m2's smart JavaScript solution, using some nice tricks to write the array shorter in Uiua.
The array needs to be in the order {"NAND" "AND" "XOR" "OR" "NOR" "XNOR"}, so:

⟜↘₁"NAND" pushes "NAND" then its tail "AND"
⊂@X.⍥₂⊸↘₁"XNOR" pushes "XNOR", its tail "NOR", its tail "OR", and that with X prepended "XOR", in opposite order to what I just wrote.


Google Sheets, 48 bytes
=mid("NANDAND XOR OR  NOR XNOR",1+4*mod(A1,6),4)

Put the bits as a text string in cell A1 and the formula in cell B1.


Charcoal, 18 bytes
×X⁼θε×NＩθ≡θηAND¦OR

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as four space or newline separated bits. Explanation:
×X⁼θε

If the first and last bits are the same then output an X.
×NＩθ

If the first bit is a 1 then output an N. (1 byte could be saved by requiring input in JSON format, which would make the Cast unnecessary.)
≡θηAND¦OR

If the first two bits are the same then output AND otherwise output OR.

Perl 5 -pl, 49 bytes
$_=(XOR,OR,NOR,XNOR,AND,(0)x3,NAND)[-6+oct"0b$_"]

Try it online!

Jelly, 22 bytes
“u{nµỤẈiBÞ]Ṛ[)®Æ8Ẇ»Ḳị@

Try it online!
Direct port of l4m2's decimal lookup table. Jelly doesn't have any such conversion from string to decimal that can handle leading zeroes as desired, so if decimal input isn't acceptable, add +1 byte for a Ḍ at the end taking list input. A permutation index or other magic formula might be able to make exploiting the structure of the output more competitive, but I've got a lunch to eat, and I'm mostly just disappointed that this beats:
Jelly, 24 bytes
^\Ḅ^1‘ị⁾XNŒPp@“AND“OR”¤Ṛ

Try it online!
Takes input as a flat list of truth values.
^\                          Scan by XOR. Since the middle two bits are always equal,
^\Ḅ  ‘ị                     bit 1 is copied to bit 3, and thus affects 2 and 4 equally.
  Ḅ                         Convert to binary.
   ^1                       XOR with 1 (i.e. flip bit 4).
     ‘ị               ¤     0-index (mod 8) into:
              “AND“OR”      ["AND", "OR"]'s
            p@              ordered Cartesian product with
       ⁾XNŒP                the powerset of "XN".
                       Ṛ    Reverse the obtained pair (which is implicitly smash-printed).


Zsh, 37 bytes
Port of l4m2's answer, with brace expansions to shorten it.
Would require tweaks for Bash, since bash interprets 0* strings as octal by default.
a=({N,}AND {X,,N,XN}OR)
<<<$a[1+$1%6]

Try it online!

R, 149 bytes
`-`=\(p)\(...)!p(...)
\(x)names(which(unlist(lapply(c(AND=`&`,OR=`|`,XOR=xor,NAND=-`&`,NOR=-`|`,XNOR=-xor),\(o)all(o(rep(0:1,2),rep(0:1,e=2))==x)))))

Attempt This Online!
Checks a named list of first-class functions for one that gives the matching results.

APL+WIN, 56 bytes
Prompts for a vector of ones and zeros:
('AND' 'NAND' 'OR' 'NOR' 'XOR' 'XNOR')['147869'⍳⍕10|2⊥⎕]

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Vim, 70 bytes
llx:s/001/AND
:s/010/XOR
:s/011/OR
:s/100/NOR
:s/101/XNOR
:s/110/NAND


Try it online!
Port of this answer made by Unrelated String.
Explanation: remove the third character, then make the appropriate substitutions. Probably the simplest answer.

Jelly, 33 bytes
“yy⁺ṗ+qƈ¶Ƒạ~×þɱL³Ð»Ḳ
“⁷4⁶’Bs4i³ị¢

Try it online!
I'll think of a way to golf that... later.

Common Lisp, 51 bytes
(princ(elt'(NAND AND XOR OR NOR XNOR)(mod(read)6)))

Try it online!
Port of l4m2's Javascript answer. It takes input from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT, since that seemed to be shorter than writing a lambda. Also, symbols are used instead of strings.
